# I can't install sanity through VS Code

Tags: sanity

When I try to install Sanity with the offered command (`npm install -g @sanity/cli` `sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022`) from the web page(https://www.sanity.io/javascriptmastery2022) through CLI it doesn't work, I receive this information on CLI:

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:16
+ npm install -g  <<<< @sanity/cli
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Answer (score 0):

The command on the website includes `&&` between the `npm install` command and the `sanity init` command. Are you including it?

If you're on Windows, you may need to run them as two separate commands:

```
npm install -g @sanity/cli
```

Then once that's done:

```
sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022
```